# Pass dynamic value from database to Carbon::now()->subMinutes()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

I have a `minutes` integer column in the db,any way to make the below query work without an additional query? Laravel 8 if it matters.

```
Contest::latest()->where('created_at','>',  Carbon::now()->subMinutes('minutes')->toDateTimeString())->paginate(4)
```

;

Reponse `ErrorException: A non-numeric value encountered in file`

Comment: You'd be better off using the MySQL functions, since Carbon won't know anything about your database fields.

Comment: Or, if you really want to use `Carbon`, you can do `Contest::latest()->get()->filter(function ($row){ return $row->created_at > Carbon::now()->subMinutes($row->minutes); });`, but for many reasons, that's a bad idea, main one being that you'd need to load _every row_ into memory first, then filter that Collection, second one being you can't directly call `paginate(4)` on that (unless you can in current version of Laravel; not sure). Just let your database do this via SQL Date/Time logic as illustrated below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this without an additional query. Carbon is a PHP library and won't work within the SQL query. However SQL does provide native functionality for what you need to do:

```
Contest::latest()
    ->where('created_at','>', DB::raw('NOW()-INTERVAL minutes MINUTE'))->paginate(4)
```

This should generally work though you may need to replace `NOW()` with whatever the DBMS provides if not using MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

From seeing documentation, I can see that the method `subMinutes()` accepts integer as a parameter, not string. Maybe try fixing that one first. When I try `Carbon::now()->subMinutes('minutes')->toDateTimeString()` running locally, I get a similar error: A non-numeric value encountered.

Information about addition and subtraction of Carbon [can be found here](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub)